# How to Improve the Accuracy of Speech Recognition Framework for UWP?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, speech-recognition, srgs

I'm currently having a problem with regards to the Accuracy of Speech Recognition framework for UWP.

The main problem is that the framework picks up other words or words that are close enough with my commands that can be found in my SRGS file.

One concrete example is I'm issuing a command like "Mic" or "Microphone" only and the actual registered command in my SRGS file is "Microphone On" but still it executes the command. I've already tried several measures to increase the accuracy like:

- Implementing SRGS file.
- Using the VoiceConfidence (Low, Medium, High) property.
- Implementing BabbleTimeout.
- Implementing Phonetics (ipa, sapi, ups) per command.
- Tried to train the built in Windows Speech Training tool.
- I also checked if it is possible to update the Framework but
  unfortunately there is no updates.

All of the said measure above did not solve my current problem, do you have any possible solutions or ideas in mind?

Answer (score 0):

For `SpeechRecognizer`, it can translate speech into text and match the corresponding command, but it cannot understand the meaning of the speech, so it will match the closest command.

To avoid misunderstandings, you can add `Mic` or `Microphone` rules to the SRGS constraints to avoid direct matching to **Microphone On**.